# Is there a max number of Authorized Redirect URIs for Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

In the Google API manager when creating a Client ID for a web application, you have the ability to add multiple authorized redirect URIs.  Does anyone know of a maximum number of URIs that can be added? Thanks

Comment: if you need more than one, you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the real number, but it is more than 32.

Source:
Currently I use 32 URI's and without any issues, so it is definetly more than that.

To commenters asking why:
We have currently 32 distinct domains, so we need 32 URI's (meaning that 32 authorized domains is not issue neither).